# How to set a custom local notification for everyday at a given time like a bible verse notification eachday

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Example : on 22/7/15 at 5pm fire notification "Hy how r u " And on 23/7/15 at 5pm get notification " how u feeling" likewise in everyday how i  fire local notification that i assigned for each day , how to assign custom notification for each day?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repeatInterval` property of  `UILocalNotification` and schedule a notification like this :

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "text that will be displayed for notification" 
notification.fireDate = NSDate()  
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName 
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSDayCalendarUnit 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

But, if you want a notification for different message every time, you will have to create a new notification for every new message and then you can schedule them for every day. You can set notification for some number of days only. Another possible approach is to use `Push Notifications`

Comment: I need different notification in different days then how i do?

Comment: You will have to create a new notification every time for every new message. You can schedule notifications for your number of days, or you can use Push Notification

Comment: Thank you can u give me an example for 2 day notification

Comment: And can u give me your facebook name so i can u could help me much better

Comment: You can use the above same code but dont use 'repeatInterval', and set 'fireDate' and run it in a loop with different messages for alert.

Comment: I don't use facebook much. You can ask me anything here.

Comment: Example please can you help

Comment: Can u give me your email id

Comment: Can u give me an example for fire different message for two days

Comment: That just explain how you fire notification , what i mean i fire custom local notification for custom day and time i

Comment: You can set date and time in "fireDate"

Comment: On 7/72015 i want to fire "hy bro" and on 8/7/2015 "dudewhtsapp" how will the code look like

Comment: Anyone please help explain

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up here looking for a solution to sending a different local notification every day in Swift 3, here's how I ended up doing it:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Good Vibes"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "GoodVibes"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    for (index, _) in Array(1...30).enumerated() {
        content.body = AppUtils.randomFunnyMessage() // Randomly selects a string
        let alarmTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * (index + 1)))
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from: alarmTime)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)

    }
```